# How do I prove that row vectors are linearly dependent if and only if the rank of matrix of mxn is less than m?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

So far I have:

Suppose that $\vec V_{1}, ...,\vec V_{m} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ are linearly dependent. Then there exists scalars $c_{1},...,c_{m}$ st. $c_{1}^{2}+...+c_{m}^{2}≠0$ and $c_{1}\vec V_{1}+...+c_{m}\vec V_{m}=\vec0$

But I am stuck on how to connect this to the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that the rank of a matrix $A$ is equivalent to the rank of its transpose $A^{\rm T}$. So the rank of $A$ is the dimension of the span of its columns, but also the dimension of the span of its rows.

Suppose the matrix formed by these vectors as rows had rank $m$. Then, the row vectors span a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with dimension $m$. How does this contradict your previous statements?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. I am unsure how it is contradictory.

Comment: You need (at least) $m$ linearly independent vectors to span an $m$ dimensional space. How many linearly independent vectors do you have?

Comment: Perfect! $\mathrm{Im}(A) = \ker(A^*)^\perp$.